# how to convert datetime from epoc to utc in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, robo3t

Hi all I have a collection name test_data and in this collect I have data like in given formate

```
Data =  [{
    "_id" : "53fe7ae0ef038fee879263d5",
    "chanal_id" : "can1",
    "instrumentnam" : "New Demo Device",
    "siteid" : "53fe741d66455060e003c2d8",
    "locationid" : "53fe74a866455060e003c2db",
    "timestamp" : 1406916000,
    "status" : "online",
    "msgtype" : "demographics",
    "fps" : "5",
    "people" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "age" : 23,
            "gender" : "male",
            "ethnicity" : null,
            "mood" : "happy",
            "ethnicity_mod" : "White",
            "mood_mod" : "Happy",
            "gender_mod" : "Female",
            "age_mod" : 22
        }
    ],
    "dateUTC" : 1409190000
},


{
    "_id" : "53fe7ae0ef038fee879263d6",
    "chanel_id" : "can1",
    "instrumentnam" : "New Demo Device",
    "siteid" : "53fe741d66455060e003c2d8",
    "locationid" : "53fe74a866455060e003c2db",
    "timestamp" : 1406917800,
    "status" : "online",
    "msgtype" : "demographics",
    "fps" : "5",
    "people" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "age" : 16,
            "gender" : "female",
            "ethnicity" : null,
            "mood" : "happy",
            "ethnicity_mod" : "White",
            "mood_mod" : "Happy"
        }
    ],
    "dateUTC" : 1409186528
},

{
    "_id" : "53fe7ae0ef038fee879263d7",
    "chanal_id" : "can1",
    "instrumentnam" : "New Demo Device",
    "siteid" : "53fe741d66455060e003c2d8",
    "locationid" : "53fe74a866455060e003c2db",
    "timestamp" : 1406918800,
    "status" : "online",
    "msgtype" : "demographics",
    "fps" : "5",
    "people" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "age" : 33,
            "gender" : "male",
            "ethnicity" : null,
            "mood" : "happy",
            "ethnicity_mod" : "White"
        }
    ],
    "dateUTC" : 1409186528
}
,

{
    "_id" : "53fe7ae0ef038fee879263d8",
    "chanal_id" : "can1",
    "instrumentnam" : "New Demo Device",
    "siteid" : "53fe741d66455060e003c2d8",
    "locationid" : "53fe74a866455060e003c2db",
    "timestamp" : 1406919800,
    "status" : "online",
    "msgtype" : "demographics",
    "fps" : "5",
    "people" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 4,
            "age" : 45,
            "gender" : "female",
            "ethnicity" : null,
            "mood" : "happy",
            "age_mod" : 5
        }
    ],
    "dateUTC" : 1409186528
},


{
    "_id" : "53fe7ae0ef038fee879263d9",
    "chanal_id" : "can1",
    "instrumentnam" : "New Demo Device",
    "siteid" : "53fe741d66455060e003c2d8",
    "locationid" : "53fe74a866455060e003c2db",
    "timestamp" : 1406920800,
    "status" : "online",
    "msgtype" : "demographics",
    "fps" : "5",
    "people" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 5,
            "age" : 14,
            "gender" : "female",
            "ethnicity" : null,
            "mood" : "angry"
        }
    ],
    "dateUTC" : 1409186528
},


{
    "_id" :"53ff927266455060e003c2e0",
    "chanal_id" : "rtsp://192.168.1.83:554/live.sdp",
    "instrumentnam" : "Test Device",
    "siteid" : "53f62abf66455068373665ff",
    "locationid" : "53f62bb86645506837366603",
    "timestamp" : 1409258116,
    "status" : "online",
    "msgtype" : "demographics",
    "fps" : "32",
    "people" : [],
    "dateUTC" : 1409258098
}]
```

which is in json format,
What I am trying to do 
1. I want to convert timestamp from epoc time to utc time in linux system. and 
2. I want to convert this json data to csv format using mongodb code in linux system.

So can anyone please help me out to do this.

Comment: Go step by step or divide the problem. 1st know how to extract json elements. 2nd after extracting required data, know how to play with date format in given framework. 3rd once you got data extracted from json you should find a way to store extracted data from Json to CSV format.